# convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n= \frac{(n)(x^n)}{(n+1)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried to prove the convergence of the series by ratio test and i have got the following form:

$\frac{(n+1)(n+1)^n(x)}{(n+2)^n(n+2)(n)}$

And i am getting stuck there, i have no idea how to proceed from here. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\dfrac{(n+1)(n+1)^n}{(n+2)^n(n+2)}=\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}$.

Recall that for any $y\in\mathbb R$, $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{y}{n}\right)^n=e^y.$$

Comment: thank you for the answer.

Comment: It's a pleasure :)

Comment: but what to do with with x/n, that will be left?

Comment: Can i just conclude, that x will not have any effect on the convergency of the series.

Comment: You asked very quickly after I gave a hint. Give it a try ;)

Comment: Start by finding the limit of the expression above.

Comment: i keep getting zero; am i wrong, was x actually a bait all along.

Comment: Nope I think you're right. That means the series converges for all $x\in\mathbb R$.